# Python + Kivy: как добавить переменную к кнопке

Tags: python, sql, kivy

Обрабатываю получаемые значения от пользователя и в далее заношу их в базу.
И что бы не лепить бутерброд из запросов, я пытаюсь получить по нажатии на кнопку имя таблицы необходимой для запроса.

```
<XZ_Screen>:
    ScreenFrame:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            cols: 2
            size_hint: 1, 1

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                cols: 1
                size_hint: 1, 1

                Button:
                    text: "zavod_1_92_25"            < ----------------------------
                    id: zavod1
                    on_press: root.test(zavod1)
                    on_press: app.root.current = 'save'
                Button:
                    text: "2 - 92\n\n25m2"
                    on_press: app.root.current = 'save'
```

Обратите внимание, проблема именно тут  "zavod_1_92_25" мне необходимо записывать именно так, иначе переменная barrel не получит верное название таблицы в SQL

** Есть ли способы сделать нормальное название, а "zavod_1_92_25" передавать в качестве значения?**

```
barrel = ''

class XZ_Screen(Screen):
    def test(self, zavod1):
        global barrel
        barrel = zavod1.text
        print(barrel)
```

```
            z = [max_id, text_1.text, text_2.text, text_3.text, text_4.text, data]
            print(z)

            postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO {table} (id, first_check, reload, second_check, count, date)
                                               VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
            record_to_insert = (z)
            cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query.format(table=barrel), record_to_insert)
```

Comment: Про питон и kivy ничего не знаю, но что если передавать "zavod_1_92_25" вместо zavod1 в метод test? Ну или просто ещё одним аргументом?

Comment: Да я вот это и пытаюсь сделать, только вот как в файле KV определить передаваемый аргумент, без привязки к ID кнопки.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение))
Тут ставим как нам надо.

```
Button:
                    text: "2 - 92\n\n25m2"            < ----------------------------
                    id: zavod1
                    on_press: root.test(zavod1)
                    on_press: app.root.current = 'save'
```

Тут присваиваем новое значение, zavod1.text = "zavod_1_92_25"

```
barrel = ''

class XZ_Screen(Screen):
    def test(self, zavod1):
        global barrel
        zavod1.text = "zavod_1_92_25"
        barrel = zavod1.text
        print(barrel)
```

Ну вот и все)